# In honor of Anton Chekhov’s birthday, January 29

Tags: alphametic

Anton Pavlovich Chekhov, the Russian playwriter and novelist was born on January 29, 1860.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Chekhov

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explanation of how to solve this manually:

First, notice the top:

> The first subtrahend must be 87. This makes A=3, and since 116 = 29×4 we must have C=1 and H=0.

What could N be?

> At least 5, since E is at least 2, so the first result is at least 150.
>  It can't be 8 or 9, because 29×8 = 232 which would force H=C.
>  It also can't be 6, because 10k+O and 29×O have the same parity, so they can't subtract to 17.

First case:

> N=5. O must be 7 to get 7-3=4, but this makes the result from subtracting 29×T 21. Since H=0, 29×T must end in 9, but then it must be 29, which is too short.

Second case:

> N=7. V=4, and O must be 5 to get 5-5=0. Now 29×T has to end in 4 for 16 to be passed down, so T=6. Now we can finally determine that the first subtraction result is 222, and E=9 and K=2 follow immediately from that.

Answer (score -1):

### 1092054 | 29
-------
87       37657

### 222
203

```
190
174
---
 165
 145
 ---
  204
  203
  ---
    1
```

this solution I get from this solver

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companyname.razkmoshed

by this puzzle

```
chekhov |**
        -----
 **     anton
 --
 ***
 ***
 ---
  ***
  ***
  ---
   ***
   ***
   ---
    ***
    ***
    ---
      *
```

and check asterisk free
there's 23 solutions of which solution 5
is the required solution

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Usually when we post answers here at PSE, we put them in [spoilers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers), so that you don't give the answer away to other puzzlers who want to give it a go.

Comment: Hi sorry
what are spoilers and were I can learn about

Comment: I gave you a link to the page that explains them. Here it is again: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers